# Authenticate to GitHub from multiple AWS EC2 instances

Tags: github, amazon-ec2

How can I authorize multiple AWS EC2 instances to pull from a private GitHub repository? Is there a way other than creating a separate key pair for each EC2 instance?

Comment: Hold on. Why are you trying to give multiple EC2 machines access to _push_ to a Github repository?

Comment: I wont be allowing push from EC2 but only read access

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely doable. You can just copy the key pairs to other EC2 hosts. But this is a risky tradeoff between security and convenience.

Comment: Suggest when you state an action has a consequence, you touch the explanation for the consequence.

Comment: Copying key pairs is risky because you'll have the same private key on multiple instances. A breach of any one instance gives the attacker access to any resource protected by the common private key.